# Should control flow and data be separate between services?

Tags: dependencies, etl

Should control flow and data be separate?

*The obvious answer in my mind is no.. but I want some more explicit arguments on why not...*

**So... here's a scenario**

- A service produces data and publishes it to a local table for an ETL separate process pick up and integrate into the main reporting data warehouse.
- There is a suggestion that the source service should notify the ETL
  that data is available... so it doesn't need to periodically check

I don't like this at all.. Why?

- It creates a structural dependency as the service needs to know about the ETL
- It also creates temporal dependency ( what if either process is down/crashed?)

If the ETL is interested in the data it should do the checking actively
 - An alternative would be for the service to actively send it to a message queue thereby delegating notification o the queuing infrastructural.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work for almost a decade on the applications where the central processes where ETL-oriented. When you work with processes that move data like that, it is very important to create a metadata about the process runs and the data loaded during those runs. It would prove invaluable for auditing purposes. It would also help you with monitoring the performance and, if done properly, correctness of the loaded data.

In addition, in your situation, it would allow the consumer processes check for the newly available data by examining the data load metadata table in the same way, rather than inventing separate queries for different data tables.